# Checking Amounts From The Paypal IPN

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I am writing a ipn handling php script, and i would like to check the customer has paid the correct amount for the product they have just purchased.

The problem i have is i'm not sure the best way to check if the payment is made in different currencies. We charge in pounds sterling, and hold our prices as pound sterling, but if someone pays in US dollars $10 obviously is not the same as £10.

Does the IPN base all its transactions in one currency (dollars i would assume) i should use as my base instead of pounds sterling, or am i going to have to do some sort of conversion?

Cheers
Luke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IPN 'mc_gross' is returned in the currency you charged the buyer for. Whichever currency the buyer finally paid doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

```
$payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
```

Through this you can verify the currency
for referece https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/IPN_PHP_41.txt

Comment: i know i can get the currency, but i'd have to convert my base price to this currency in order to check it, and i dont really want to do this

Comment: <input type="hidden" value="GBP" name="currency_code"> will add currency as british pound and user will not be able to change it during purchase I think so.